# Linear Function Borel-Caratheodory

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, riemann-zeta

I´m working on a book and in a proof it says from

$\max_{0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi}Re(F(Re^{i\theta}))\ll R(\log(R))^2$

follows with

$\sup_{n\ge1}\frac{R^n}{n!}\vert F^{(n)}(0)\vert\leq 2A$ (Borel-Caratheodory)

that F is an linear function. But hwo do you consider that? I only get, that $F^{(n)}\ll\log(R)^2$. What is the idea to get it

For notice :

$F(s)$ is a ,for $\vert s\vert\leq R,~R\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, holomorph function with $F(0)=0$.

$A:=\max_{\vert s\vert=R}Re(F(s))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A(R)=R(\log(R))^2$ we get from the Borel-Caratheodry relations $\vert F^{(n)}(0)\vert\leq 2n!\frac{(\log(R))^2}{R^{n-1}}$

If $n \ge 2$ RHS converges to $0$ as $R \to \infty$ so we get the result